# What is the default Web browser on Android?

Tags: browsers, android

What is the default Web browser on Android devices?

Are there weird Web browser set by default that I should be aware of (to test my mobile Website on it)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That depends on the device and version. The most common, particularly for less new devices is the Android Browser. Like Chrome, it is based on Webkit and identifies itself as:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android x.x; Build/xx)
AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari 530/17
```

Most recent - at least those from Google - devices use [Chrome for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en) instead. Phones use the token Mobile in the user-agent strings while tablets do not:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android x.x; Build/xx)
AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xx.xx Safari/<WebKit Rev>

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android x.x; Build/xx)
AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xx.xx Mobile Safari/<WebKit Rev>
```

Comment: Do you know where can I download the Android Browser .apk?

Answer (score 5):

Androids use the Android Browser as well as a few others that they can download. You can test your website on using an [Android VM](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) on your local machine. While for iPhone, iPad testing I recommend you get yourself these devices as there is no VM's available for these devices and the online emulators are not the real deal.

Comment: There is an emulator for iOS devices: XCode.  XCode has a Simulator that emulates iOS devices.  But you need Mac OS X to run it.