# Android browser compatibility checking

Tags: css, android, compatibility

Apart from the suggestions made in [How can I see what my web site looks like in various browsers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-can-i-see-what-my-web-site-looks-like-in-various-browsers), I have actively downloaded the 3 major browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer) and I check my website designs using the actual browsers along with Edge which is now provided automatically in Windows 10.

For belt and braces, I also double check mobile screen media queries and accessibility on my Samsung mobile phone and iPad.

To check percentage compatibility for global users I often use [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com) to get an idea on what percentage of web users globally will be able to use the CSS/HTML5/JS function.

Now even though I know it is highly accessible, out of interest, I went to see how accesible the CSS property `z-index` is and I got the following information.

[image: can I use dot com compatibility chart for CSS property z index]

Unfortunately this is one of the rare situations where you don't get a global percentage score like you do with CSS `content-visibility` (see: https://caniuse.com/css-content-visibility) but looking at the individual browsers, "Android Browser" is given.

What is "Android Browser"? Should we really be worried about it's lack of compatibility with `z-index` when [it seems that for 7 years at least](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47615/what-is-the-default-web-browser-on-android), "Android Browser" has been dropped in favour of Google Chrome?

Comment: "lack of compatibility with z-index" - In the table you posted, the grey cells indicate "unknown", not that it's necessarily "not supported".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output I get from caniuse.com is different and, I believe more informative -

[image]

This says to me that Android Browser used to be based on its own code in 2014/2015, but is now based on the Chromium 81.   This is backed up by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998074/what-is-the-engine-of-android-native-browser.  It is interesting to note that the Android browser field in 2020 says 81 in green on my output, but 81 and grey on your output - I posit this has to do with the algorithm they are using to display the summaries being faulty.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Just out of interest, how did you get this output from caniuse.com?  It is definitely more informative.

Comment: No idea - I've never used the site before. Indeed I was surprised I could not get output that looked like yours (which is what I was trying to do). Maybe they are doing A/B testing?

Answer (score 1):

If 100% of your users use the Android browser according to your server logs then, yes, you should be worried.

I had two restaurants I created web sites for. One was next to a large financial institution and many of their employees ate at that restaurant for lunch. Logs showed that visitors to their web site had something like 60% visitors using IE9 (a while back). The visitors log of the other restaurant showed IE visitors of any version of IE was 10%.

Always go by your visitors and not any internet web site's opinion.